# KDE 4.7.2 - Change order of open windows in task manager?

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, task-manager, kde-4

I am using KDE 4.7.2 at the moment. I'm used to move the windows in the task manager by drag and drop. In earlier KDE versions this worked. But somehow it won't work now and I didn't find a solotion on the internet. Is there a solution for this or is this feature abandoned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Task Manager Settings->Sorting->Manually